# Sorting on basis of multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have three database table fields. And want to assign an sequence number accordingly.

First field is `percentage`, `10_percentage`, `date_of_birth`. Now if values matches on `percentage` then comparison has to be made for shortest or earlier `10_percentage` between conflicting records at percentage stage, even if conflict persists for `10_percentage` then `date_of_birth` has to be checked. I am stuck and cannot find a way to do this.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried. Maybe post some code?

Comment: Have you tried using a `ORDER BY percentage, 10_percentage, date_of_birth` clause? Or is the problem more complicated than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I this what you were looking for?

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, percentage, 10_percentage, date_of_birth
  FROM table
  ORDER BY percentage, 10_percentage, date_of_birth;
```

[This](http://www.fromdual.com/ranking-mysql-results) link explains about ranking in mysql. And [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) shows you using multiple columns in sorting